# Double inequality with a certain number of reals

Tags: inequality

I've encountered the following problem that I don't know how to solve:

Given positive natural $n$ and positive real $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ prove that there exists such positive natural $N$ that 

$(1+\frac1n)^N\ge 2 (x_1+x_2+...+x_{n-1}) + \frac{N}nx_n\ge N^n$.

I don't even know how to start with either of the parts, leave alone both of them simultaneously. I supposed it may be done by the inequality of means but my attempts didn't show anything interesting.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: @EricTowers x. My bad

Comment: If $n=2$ and $x_1=x_2=1$ the inequality reduces to $(3/2)^N\geq N-1\geq N^2$, and the second inequality can't be true for any $N$. Do you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: @JoelMoreira Thank you. I made an error. The correct “developed” fraction in the middle should be reducible to 2. I was too careless. I know it changes a lot. Could you please help me nonetheless?

Comment: Hm, still when $n=2$ and $x_1=x_2=1/4$ the second inequality becomes $1/2+N/8 \geq N^2$ which does not have a solution $N$.

Comment: More generally, the middle term is linear in $N$ and the right hand side is quadratic when $n=2$, so the second inequality will probably have no solution, unless something changes more dramatically.